# How can I create a random, circular partner assignment?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm allowing users to register on my site for a 'game'; as is normal, they all receive unique IDs.  At a given point in time, registration will cease.  At that time, I would like to run code to assign partners, but not pairs.

So, if I had the following:

> +--------+-------+
>   | user_id | partner |
>   +--------+-------+
>   |   1 |    |
>   |   3 |     |
>   |   7 |     |
>   |    11 |    |
>   |    12 |    |
>   |    18 |    |
>   +--------+-------+

what would I do to end up with something like this:

> +--------+--------+
>   | user_id | partnr |
>   +--------+--------+
>   |   1 |    7 |
>   |   3 |   12  |
>   |   7 |   18  |
>   |    11 |    1  |
>   |    12 |    11 |
>   |    18 |    3 |
>   +--------+--------+

1,7,18,3,12,11;1,7,18,3,12,11

```
$query = "SELECT users FROM tabl";
$result = mysql_query ($query)
    or die ("Query '$query' failed with error message: \"" . mysql_error () . '"');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $users[] = $row[0];
}

$current = end($users);
$partners = array();
foreach ($users as $user)
{
        $partners[$user] = $current;
        $current = $user;
}
print_r($partners);
```

This seems to work, thanks to Sjoerd, but I need to write it back to the partner column.

Comment: Is there a concept of a team?

Comment: No, there are no teams. 'Players' act independently.  Similar to musical chairs.

Comment: There are two independent loops (teams of three) in the example output. Is this really what you meant?

Comment: No, bobince.  I understand that it kinda forms teams like that, but that is not the intention.  It's as if I'm trying to tell everyone who stands to their left in a circle.  I will edit the desired result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Retrieve the list of users.
- Shuffle this list (optional).
- Assign each user the next one in the list as partner, where the last user gets the first user as partner.

Code to loop through the array and assign partners:

```
$users = array('john', 'jack', 'jones', 'joelle', 'jesica');

$current = end($users);
$partners = array();
foreach ($users as $user)
{
        $partners[$user] = $current;
        $current = $user;
}
print_r($partners);
```

Comment: I thought about this, but I could not find in any of my books or online how to code that.  If nobody has time to write it out, I understand, but could someone point me in the direction of which functions to use?  
I would prefer to shuffle, however, I do not think that is wise, as I do not want to risk a user being his own partner.  If there is a way to randomize with each new 'game' without the risk of a user being his own partner, that would be fantastic.

Comment: google "shuffle list code". There seems to be suggestions for a number of languages. If you follow the instructions in the above answer, there is no risk of a user being assigned to himself as a partner - except if there is only one user.

Comment: What would this look like?  Would it be possible to help me build off of the framework below?

<?php
$query = "SELECT user_id FROM table" ;
$results = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$array = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
{
    $array[] = $row;
}

shuffle($array);

print_r($array);
?>

Comment: I've edited my answer with a code example of how you would loop through the array and assign partners.

Comment: If you shuffle the list and then assign each player the next as a partner, the next might be himself...

Comment: @Sjoerd ... ok, now I understand, you shuffle the list and assign the partner from the shuffled list to the shuffled list ... I thought before, you would use the original list and assign partners in the shuffled list ... maybe you want to add this in the code sample ($users = shuffle($users)) for other dumb people like me ;-)

Comment: Sjoerd, your solution works except that it is entirely predictable.  I added an ORDER BY RAND() to achieve my desired result.  Thank you very much!  Now I just need to write it back to the table...?

Answer (score 1):

- Select out the ids in a random order
- Have two copies of the resulting array
- Pop one element of the end of one array and push it on the top (ie offset the entire array by one)
- Update the table as user_id,partner_id pairs

  ```
  $results = mysql_query("SELECT user_ids FROM -tablename- ORDER BY RAND()");

  $user_ids = array();
  $partner_ids = array();

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results))
  {
      $user_ids[] = $row['user_id'];
      $partner_ids[] = $rowp['user_id'];
  }

  $lastPartnerId = array_pop($partner_ids);
  array_unshift($partner_ids,$lastPartnerId);

  for($i=0;$i<count($user_ids);$i++)
  {
      mysql_query("UPDATE -tablename- SET partner_id = {$partner_ids[$i]} WHERE user_id = {$user_ids[$i]}");
  }
  ```

Comment: I am receiving this error:  
mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: This means mysql_query returns false, which means that the query failed.

Comment: "SELECT user_ids ..." should be "SELECT user_id ..." therefore the failing query I guess ...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if there are mistakes ... I havn't been coding PHP for a long time ...

```
$i = rand(1, length($players) - 1)
for ($p = 0; $p < length($players); $p++)
{
    $partners[$p] = $players[$i];
    if (++$i > length($players))
    {
        $i = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: If $i == 0 then everybody gets himself as a partner.